# getExternalStoragePublicDirectory deprecated warning persists below Android Q

Tags: android, scoped-storage

Since Android 10, `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` was *deprecated* in favor of other alternatives such as `MediaStore` or `getExternalFilesDir`.

I am saving videos to the `"DCIM->MyFolder"` directory.

- For Android 10 and above, I use `MediaStore` to get the `FileDescriptor`:

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor;
    Uri videoUri;

    ContentResolver resolver = this.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/" + "MyFolder");

    videoUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

    ParcelFileDescriptor descriptor = this.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(videoUri, "w");
    fileDescriptor = descriptor.getFileDescriptor();

    return fileDescriptor;
}
```

Then open an `OputputStream` to be able to write the file:
`outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileDescriptor);`

- For devices below Android 10, I use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`:

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    String outputPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "MyFolder") + "/";
}
```

Then open the `OutputStream`: `outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + fileName);`

**The problem:** Despite targeting the right Android versions, Android Studio still gives me a warning about the deprecated `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` method.

**Question:** What is the correct way to get the `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM` path without using deprecated methods?

**Note:**

1. MediaStore cannot be used below API 29 because of this `MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH`
2. I cannot use `getExternalFilesDir` because it returns a path to the application internal storage and my saved videos wouldn't be visible in gallery.

Comment: `MediaStore cannot be used below API 29 because of this MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH` Of course you can use media store then too. The media store existed long before Q. Only column .RELATIVE_PATH is new. The old column is .DATA.

Comment: `Question: What is the correct way to get the /storage/emulated/0/DCIM path without using deprecated methods?` Just use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() as always.

Comment: Right now I am using getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() for Android below 10 and it works... but Android Studio warns me that the method is deprecated and I want to get rid of that warning, that's why I am looking for alternatives

Comment: Use it as you did before 10. There is no alternative  It is already undeprecated again. And strange: my Android Studio does not warn. Dont make you a problem where there isnt one.